# Redirect www to non-www nginx

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx

I'm using nginx as reversed proxy, apache as web server. We're using SSL. The problem is that our SSL provider doesn't support www. So we have to redirect it to non-www. But we got the issue with https://www.domain.com. It didn't redirect to https://domain.com. It shows the invalid Certificate instead. I tried to work on both nginx rules and .htaccess but none of them worked.

Comment: Get a refund, and find an SSL certificate vendor who can do their jobs properly.

Comment: @MichaelHampton beat me to it.

Comment: I just need to redirect from https:/www.domain.com to https:/domain.com. That is all

Comment: It's impossible without valid certificate. Ditto.